# Is there a transpose function in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

Hi I look for a transpose function in Elixir.
For example I have this kind of array `a` and after calling a function the result should be `b`:

```
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
b = transpose(a)
b => [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There isn't one in Elixir currently, but you could create your own with:

```
def transpose([]), do: []
def transpose([[]|_]), do: []
def transpose(a) do
  [Enum.map(a, &hd/1) | transpose(Enum.map(a, &tl/1))]
end
```

Comment: Another nice implementation I've found in [this wiki](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Matrix_transposition#Elixir)
`transpose = fn(m)-> List.zip(m) |> Enum.map(&Tuple.to_list(&1)) end`

Comment: actually there is no need for an explicit param in your capture `Enum.map(&Tuple.to_list/1)` just works fine.

Comment: @IvanKozik OTP 19.1 Elixir 1.4.2 no problem on empty lists

Answer (score 23):

There (still) isn't one in Elixir, but you can use:

```
def transpose(rows) do
  rows
  |> List.zip
  |> Enum.map(&Tuple.to_list/1)
end
```

Answer (score 11):

Since Elixir v1.12, you can use the following to transpose a two-dimensional list:

```
Enum.zip_with(list, &Function.identity/1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly different solution:

```
def transpose(m) where length(m) <2, do: m
def transpose(m) do
  for i <- 0..length(m)-1 do
    Enum.reduce(m,[], fn x,acc -> acc ++ [Enum.at(x,i)] end)
  end
end
```

where `m` is your matrix.