# Take nth of list

Tags: elixir

How to turn this data

```
[
  [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
  [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
  [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
  [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
]
```

To this data

```
[
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
  ...
]
```

In some other languages like php, i could use the index to iterate over the data. Basically it just flip the column into a row.

Comment: If what you want is to get the first element of each list, you could do `Enum.map(your_list, &List.first/1)`

Comment: @sbacaro Hi, thanks for the fast response. I just updated my question. I'm not only taking the first key/list. Instead i'm taking the nth of every column, and flip it to a row.

Comment: Then you can replace the `&List.first/1` bit for `&(Enum.at(&1, n))`. So: `Enum.map(your_list, &(Enum.at(&1, n)))`

Comment: If you are looking to transpose your 'matrix 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23705074/is-there-a-transpose-function-in-elixir

Comment: `List.zip(data)` should do the job.

Comment: Thank you guys for such a great response. ```data |> List.zip |> Enum.map(fn x -> Tuple.to_list(x) end)``` worked.